# How to to bind an Onclick event to a menu item if content equl to

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I'm adding multiple Boostrap modals to a website (modals have different content) but I want to add append an onclick event e.i if menu item "request" here i want to add an onclick="request()" to fire the appropriate modal when user click on it.

I know I can simply add this manually but it would be great to learn how to do this dynamically with javascript/jquery!

thank you alot!!

Comment: Show us what you have tried so far

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+attach+onclick+handler+in+javascript&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b-1-ab

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can write the it manually but dynamic will always a good practice.
if your model has any thing common more like class.

```
$(".class").on("click",function(){
    // your code or action you want to perform.
});
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: This is nice but what if all the link have the same class? can I select by content .ei ("Support Donation")

Comment: in that case you can change it based on ID